# html video tag from stream in html refreshing frame only on scroll

Tags: html, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I have a video tag that receives a video stream through WebRTC (I'm using peerJS)

```
function getVideoStream() {
    PEER.on('call', function(call) {
        call.answer(); // Answer the call with an A/V stream.
        call.on('stream', onReceiveStream);
    });
}


function onReceiveStream(stream){
    $('video').prop('src',window.URL.createObjectURL(stream));
}
```

Everything is working fine, but my video is freezing, it only works correctly if i scroll up and down, so i'm assuming it got something to do with the video redrawing the frames.

Is there anything I should do to keep it from happening ?

Thanks,

Comment: does the video have autoplay=true set?

Comment: What browser are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thank you @PhilippHancke that was it!!